# Correct way to verify split files with 7-zip?

Tags: compression, 7-zip

I'm using the 7z.exe in a script to create some archives with `7z.exe a -tzip -v100m`, when the archives are created i verify them with `7z.exe t`. When compressing big files, the result is for example:

`archive.zip.001` `archive.zip.002`

When verifying the archives, running `7z.exe t archive.zip.001` returns **Everything is Ok**, but running
`7z.exe t archive.zip.002` it just says **Can't open as archive: 1**. I'm assuming that since when extracting the files, you only run for example `7z.exe x archive.zip.001`, and not `7z.exe x archive.zip.002`, the same goes for verifying the files? That is, you only need to run `7z.exe t archive.zip.001` to verify the split archive. But i cant find a definite source on this when searching around, and would just like some confirmation that I'm doing this the right way.

7-zip is version 18.06

Comment: You can verify this yourself. Damage the `.002` file and see if the test for `.001` fails.

Comment: Good idea! Don't know why i didn't think of that. Openeded up `.002` in a hex editor and damaged it. Verification of `.001` now fails, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! You can post that as an answer. Self-answering is welcome on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [gronostaj suggested](https://superuser.com/questions/1658441/correct-way-to-verify-split-files-with-7-zip?noredirect=1#comment2539374_1658441), i tried damaging the `.002` file and then running the verification of the `.001` file again, which now fails. So my initial assumption was correct.